# MongoDB - Indexing embedded keys when the embedded keys are URIs

Tags: indexing, mongodb

I'm having a problem getting indexes in MongoDB to work correctly when I'm indexing into embedded documents.  The indexes work fine if the inner key is a simple string but because of my data format the inner keys often need to be URIs and this doesn't seem to work, looking at the Mongo log when I try and create the indexes it says the indexes are created but it adds every document to the index.

Is there a reason why indexes on property names of this type does not work and what can I do to avoid this issue?

**Example Document**

```
{ 
  name: "some-name",
  graph: 
  { 
    "http://example.org/subject" : 
    {
        "http://example.org/predicate" : 
        [ 
          { "value" : "http://example.org/object", "type" : "uri" } 
        ] 
    }
  }
}
```

**Alternative Schema which avoids the Issue**

I've now changed my code to use an alternative schema which avoids this issue since the URIs are now always values rather than property names and the schema allows me to leverage multikey indexes in MongoDB properly:

```
{
  name : "some-name",
  graph : [
            { 
              "subject" : "<http://example.org/subject>" ,
              "predicate" : "<http://example.org/predicate>" ,
              "object" : "<http://example.org/object>"
            }
          ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of your document?

Comment: Which field are you indexing on? Looking at your example document, I'm pretty sure that you're going to need a slightly different schema.

Comment: Yes I think I might, I was hoping I could get away with reusing the existing JSON serialization of the abstract syntax (which is RDF - the above value of the graph property is the RDF/JSON serialization) but think I may have to go with another format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have dots in keys.

The driver [should reject this](http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-151) before it gets to the database.

Comment: Yes, this bug (reported by me) will be fixed in 2.3.

Comment: Will report a bug for my relevant driver

Answer (score 1):

Dots and $ are resolved chars and can not be used in a property name because they have a special meaning to the server. $ are used to mark server operators. Dots are used for a short notation for properties in sub documents.

Short example:
db.postings.find( { "author.name" : "joe" } );

You can read more about that here:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29

One way to solve that is to encode . and $ with some other values. A second way could be to have the url as property below the element.

```
{ 
  name: "some-name",
  graph: 
  { 
    site1: 
    {
        url:"http://example.org/subject",
        predicates : 
        [ 
          { "url":"http://example.org/predicate", "value" : "http://example.org/object", "type" : "uri" } 
        ] 
    }
  }
}
```